# Kivy Screen object reports parent as None Type only during on_key_up

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am using a screen widget to create a slider image with kivy. When triggering the event on_touch_down, it runs normally.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import kivy, os
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
#from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

#Builder.load_file('/home/kzulfazriawan/Dropbox/project/Around/kv/introduct.kv')

clocking = 0

class INTRODUCTSCREEN(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(INTRODUCTSCREEN, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        global clocking

        imaging  = Image()
        boxes = BoxLayout()

        self.__image_location = kwargs['image_dir'].decode('utf-8')

        try :
            imaging.source = self.__image_location
        except ValueError,e:
            print e

        self.__time_count = clocking
        self.__limit_count = round(2 * kwargs['counting'])
        self.__situation = kwargs['situation']

        boxes.add_widget(imaging)
        self.add_widget(boxes)
        self.name = kwargs['current_name']
        self.size = imaging.texture_size

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.eventCountdown, 1.)

        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up = self._on_keyboard_up)


    def eventCountdown(self, dt):

        self.__time_count += 1

        if self.__time_count > self.__limit_count:
            self.changeEventIntro(self.__situation)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)
        self._keyboard = None

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):

        self.changeEventIntro(self.__situation)

    def _on_keyboard_up(self, *args):

        keycode = args[1]
        if keycode[1] == 'enter':
            self.changeEventIntro(self.__situation)

        return True        

    def changeEventIntro(self, situation):

        Clock.unschedule(self.eventCountdown)
        self.parent.transition = FadeTransition()
        os.unlink(self.__image_location)


        if situation == 'finalscreen':

            self.parent.introduct('destroy')
            self.parent.prepareGamePlay('startup_panel')
        else:

            self.parent.current = self.parent.next()
```

However, when I try to add some event widget with on_key_up, it triggers an error:

```
File "/home/kzulfazriawan/Dropbox/project/Around/data/script/ready_to_compile/introduct.py", line 76, in changeEventIntro
         self.parent.transition = FadeTransition()
     AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transition'
```

If I run my application and click the screen then it works but when I try to press the "enter" button. The error is triggered.

Why does the reference to self.parent trigger an error for on_key_up but not on_touch_down?

Comment: Could you post a full runnable example?